# what is 'undefined reference to `pow''

Tags: c

I have a [codepad](http://codepad.org/NuD9TMSE) .

On line 15 inside a for function

```
 for(i=2; i<=90; i+=2){
    int j=0+i;
    printf("%i\n",i);
    power=pow(inp,j);
    factor=factorial(i);
    if(i%4==0)fAns += power/factor;
    else fAns -= power/factor;
  }
```

the line `power=pow(inp,j);` I added `j` instead of just using `i` because it gave me the same error. `undefined reference to 'pow'`.

If I replace `j` with 2, then it works just fine but when I use `j=i` it wont work. Is there a problem with incrementing this line?

I want this to increment and not throw me an error.

Comment: Gcc is cheating :) See [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html#mpfropts)

Answer (score 29):

You need to link with the math library.  With gcc, this would mean passing `-lm` during linking.

The reason it doesn't complain when you use `2` as the exponent value is because the compiler is optimizing the `pow` call out.

Comment: Huh. Does `gcc` really do that optimization? That's wild.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Yes it optimizes to `inp*inp`

Comment: WoW nice answer, wouldn't expect it to optimize the call

Comment: Yes, `gcc` will (I believe) actually optimize any call to `pow` that has a constant exponent, including exponents like `0.25` or `0.75` which will be optimized a series of `sqrt` calls instead.