# How do I build and run C files that use math.h functions in VSCode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

As mentioned here: [Undefined reference to pow( ) in C, despite including math.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824134/undefined-reference-to-pow-in-c-despite-including-math-h), I can build C files that use math.h functions in Linux Ubuntu only in the terminal, by putting `-lm` at the end of `gcc -o namefile namefile.c`. But I want to build and run a C code that uses math.h in VSCode specifically. How do I do that?

Comment: Add it to your libraries.

Comment: How exactly do you "build and run a C code in VSCode"? Do you use some extension to run the compiler for you?

Comment: I build and run them by pressing F6 and I use the extensions "Code Runner", "C/C++ Compile Run" and "C/C++" for C.

Answer (score 7):

You can do the same in VS Code using a [custom task configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) for compiling your .c file.

Let's say we have this test.c file with math.h.

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PI 3.14159265 //defines the value of PI

/* Calculate the volume of a sphere from a given radius */
double volumeFromRadius(double radius) {
    return (4.0/3.0) * PI * pow(radius,3.0f);
}

int main(void) {
    double radius = 5.1;
    printf("The volume for radius=%.2f is %.2f", radius, volumeFromRadius(radius));
}
```

#### **Step 1**: Create a *tasks.json* file

This is for compiling/building your codes.
To auto-create this:

1. Open the .c file
2. Open the command palette
3. Select **C/C++: Build and Debug Active File** (added by the C/C++ extension)
4. Select your compiler (ex. mine is `gcc-7`)

That will auto-create a *tasks.json* file and attempt to compile your .c file, which we expect to fail because it is missing the `-lm` flag. So, edit the contents of the *tasks.json* file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Compile test.c",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc-7",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Q/test.out",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Q/test.c",
                "-lm"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I added the `-lm` flag to the `gcc` arguments and `label`-ed it as "Compile test.c". Modify the paths to the .c and .out files appropriately to match your environment.

More info on the schema here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks.

#### **Step 2**: Create a *launch.json* file

This is for running your codes.
To auto-create this:

1. Open the command palette
2. Select **Debug: Open launch.json**
3. Select **C++ (GDB/LLDB)**

Then edit it to run the expected .out file.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run test.c",
            "preLaunchTask": "Compile test.c",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Q/test.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/Q",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

Notice that the `preLaunchTask` should specify the same task label in *tasks.json*. Again, modify the paths appropriately to match your environment, especially the path and filename to the .out file.

#### **Step 3**: Compile and Run It

Now, I don't use (or like) Code Runner.
I use the built-in debugger configuration of VS Code.

Click the debugger from the left-hand side and select "Run test.c" from the dropdown.

[image]

This should compile your .c file, run it, and print out any outputs to the Terminal panel.

[image]

By default, the focus goes to the run output. But if you also want to see the compilation/build logs, you can select the Task from the dropdown.

Comment: Check out my [VSCode extension: C Toolkit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UsmanMehmood.c-toolkit) that automates all these steps and helps you create C projects with ease.

Answer (score 0):

Add `"-lm"` option to the `"args"` array in the `.vscode/tasks.json` file:

```
"tasks": [
  {
    ...
    "args": [
      ...
      "-lm",
     ],
    ...
  }
]
...
```