# c language math library error when compiling (pow)

Tags: c, ide, pow

I pasted the wrong error in my question by mistake. Now I have fixed my question.

I'm having a problem compiling a program I wrote using math.h library.
I can compile the program in my computer with visual 08 and codeblocks, but then I try to use my school IDE I get some errors.

`` /tmp/ccD2ZV6Q.o: In function `main':
knit2.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `pow'
knit2.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to `pow'
knit2.c:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

I have to use this command to be able to compile it:

`gcc knit2.c -lm -o knit2.exe`

Is there anything I could do to my code to fix this so it can compile using `gcc knit2.c`

Comment: typo: `\ ` --> `\n`

Comment: The error is nothing to do with `pow()`.  You need the `-lm` option unless you eliminate the call to `pow()`.

Comment: Note that the C11 standard [§6.4.4.4 Character constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4) references a (non-normative) [footnote 77](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note77) which says: _… If any other character follows a backslash, the result is not a token and a diagnostic is required. …_  A blank is in the 'any other character' category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake seems to be in your printf statement.

`"You will be able to make %.f blankets\ "`

Remove the backslash (\), that's what probably causing the error.

Comment: Or replace the blank after the backslash with `n` to give `\n` line ending.

Comment: I pasted the wrong error in my question by mistake :/  `/tmp/ccD2ZV6Q.o: In function main':
knit2.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to pow'
knit2.c:(.text+0xce): undefined reference to pow'
knit2.c:(.text+0x11b): undefined reference to pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status `

Comment: As Jonathan mentioned, you need the -lm option to include math library in the build. See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824134/undefined-reference-to-pow-in-c-despite-including-math-h

Comment: Maybe your school IDE does not link that library by default, and that's why you need to give -lm option. The -o option and giving the name of executable after it should not be needed.

Comment: @tikna thank you!. seems to be that my school's IDE is not linking like you said. I had to turn in my project with a comment stating the situation. thx again.