# #include<math.h> not working in vscode (ubuntu)

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I just installed ubuntu via dual boot on my laptop and further installed vscode along with `build-essenttial` command.
Everything is working fine in my current knowledge but in any code where #include<math.h> is used and inside main function pow() is used. Vs code is giving this error. I have tried every possible thing but can't resolve it.

**image :**

[image]

Comment: Add `-lm` flag. I though it was added by default...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to pow( ) in C, despite including math.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824134/undefined-reference-to-pow-in-c-despite-including-math-h)

Comment: You need to link your C file to `libm`, eg: `gcc main.c -lm -o main`

Comment: For future questions please provide a [mre] and the full text of error messages as text not screenshots. Please also don't tag c++ for c questions and visa versa